# How to create a Select statement which contains a SUM on a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a select statement that is causing me issues, i have two tables:

```
Customer table

ID  Month4Value Month5Value

1      24           5

Orders table

ID    Year   Month  Value  Quantity

1     2018    8      10     2
1     2018    4      2      1
1     2018    6      10     4
1     2018    4      7      3
```

I currently have the below view:

```
Create View Values as 
Select ID, Year, Month, ROUND(SUM(Value*Quantity),2) as NewQuantity
FROM Orders
GROUP BY ID, Year, Month
```

The below select statement is what i am trying to run

```
Select Customer.ID, Customer.Month5Value, NewQuantity
from Customer inner join Values on Customer.ID = Values.ID
where ROUND(Customer.Month5Value, 2) <> ROUND(NewQuantity,2)
AND Values.Year = 2018
AND Values.Month = 5
```

What i am trying to achieve is to find any mismatches between the Orders table and the Customer table. In the above example, what i am expecting is to highlight that the value in Customer.Month5Value does not match the total of the (Quantity*Value) from the Orders table.

As there are 0 orders for Month 5 in the Orders Table, the Month5Value should be 0. However, it returns no entrys.

Any thoughts about what i have missed?

EDIT -
I have updated my query to this:

```
Select Customer.ID, Customer.Month5Value, NewQuantity
from Customer left join Values on Customer.ID = Values.ID
where ROUND(Customer.Month5Value, 2) <> ISNULL((Select NewQuantity from Customer left join Values on Customer.ID = Values.ID where Values.Month = 5 and Values.Year = 2018),0)
```

This has given me a list of IDs which have an incorrect amount in Month5Value on the Customer table, but displays lines for each month entry

```
ID      Month5Value     NewQuantity
1           5                24
1           5                40
1           5                20
```

How can i adjust this so that I get one line per ID with the correct value for NewQuantity (either 0 or NULL in this case)?

Comment: You cant possibly have a view like that.  Select from what?

Comment: You should include the tag for the SQL dialect you're using (MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, etc.) in the tags input.

Comment: View needs table.  How can you create view without `FROM` clause?

Comment: My apologies  there is a from clause it's from the Orders table.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, i'm using microsoft sql-server and have updated the tag with this.

Comment: Just as an aside, using the reserved word `values` as a view name (or any kind of name) is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think the INNER JOIN is removing any records which are missing from VALUES. Replacing the INNER JOIN with LEFT JOIN may give the result you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried replacing the join with a left join but did not have any success

Comment: @Razoack Left join will not work as there is no month column in Customer.

Comment: @Razoack You cannot create a record for month 5 with 0 or null as no record for month 5 exists.